# How to insert and update data into EF more then one tables at a time

Tags: c#, wpf, entity-framework

One of the WPF form of my project should be use two entity tables.
[image]

The form has fields from both tables: **Name**, **Description**, **IsActive**, **CreatedDate**, **CreatedBy**, **UpdatedDate**, **UpdatedBy**.
How to create common source for form based on two tables?
How to create save and update methods to insert and update data for both tables at a time?

Thanks.

Comment: What does your code look like? Can't you just do multiple operations before calling `context.ApplyChanges()`?

Comment: You should create an instance of department and set it's properties. Including the list of employeedept. Assuming you're not retaining your instance of dbcontext ( which you should not ). You then new up a dbcontext. And call dbcontext.Departments.Add with your department object. Then dbcontext.savechanges.

Answer (score 0):

If you use lazy loading. You can create instance Department with inner list EmployeeDept then you add Department, EF automatic add to two table

Comment: Hi Văn Phú Lê. Thanks for reply.
I'm new in C# development with EF. I will appreciate if you show how it to do by sample code with detail explanation.
Thanks.